# Am having, Server error! coming from the file .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Server error!
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 500

```
I add this script below to a .htaccess file which is connected with an application on my local server <br/>
# Redirect search results
 RewriteRule ^search-results/find-(.*)/all-words-(on|off)/page-([0-9]+)/?$ 
 index.php?SearchResults&SearchString=$1&AllWords=$2&Page=$3 [L]
 RewriteRule ^search-results/find-?(.*)/all-words-(on|off)/?$ 
 index.php?SearchResults&SearchString=$1&AllWords=$2&Page=1 [L].

`It should display and redirect the search result on the website`
```

Comment: An "internal server error" (actually a http status 500) is just the minimal information the server hands out to requesting clients. It does not mention the actual issue there, because that clearly might expose internal information you do not want all your clients to known. You as the own however have access to more information. Your http server writes an error log file. That is where you can simply read what the actual issue is.

Comment: The rules you posted look fine so far (though I miss the `RewriteEngine on`). But the issue might be that you simply did not load the rewriting module. Which would lead to a "command not found" error. In "internal server error".

Comment: "The rules you posted look fine" - Although you can't simply split directives over multiple lines as posted in the question. If the code is really formatted like that then that would certainly cause a 500 error. (Although there are other errors with the formatting, so it's a tad unclear.)